# Java Map Compute BiFunction Cannot Recognize Lambda Function

Tags: java, lambda

I am learning the Map class in Java and cannot manage to get the `compute` method to work.

I found a good tutorial [here](http://blog.jooq.org/2014/02/14/java-8-friday-goodies-map-enhancements/) that demonstrate how you can pass a BiFunction or lambda function to compute, in a way like this:

```
System.out.println(map.compute("A", 
    (k, v) -> v == null ? 42 : v + 41));
```

The logic is pretty straightforward, get the value whose key is 'A', check if the value is null, then set the value to 42, otherwise, the existing value plus 41.

However, when I try to run the code in Eclipse, it is complaining

```
Multiple markers at this line
- v cannot be resolved to a variable
- Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete 
 Assignment
- v cannot be resolved to a variable
- Syntax error on token ">", invalid (
- v cannot be resolved to a variable
- Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression
- k cannot be resolved to a variable
```

I am pretty sure the JRE environment that I have been using Java 8, and wondering if I can get any help here. I did the validation by removing all the other java environments in Eclipse and by adding in `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));` to double check the output is `1.8.0_65`.

[image]

Comment: Check your compilation preferences and verify that the source level is 1.8, and not something below.

Comment: To elaborate, the Java version you use to launch Eclipse and the Java version that Eclipse used to launch your sample program are distict from the Java version that Eclipse uses to compile your source.  Eclipse has its own compiler, so it's likely the compiler version you've set (for the project or globally) is not 1.8.